# python appscript module - creating k. type objects

Tags: python, macos, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

I'm learning and enjoying the appscript module, but I'm a little confused
about how to instantiate basic k. type objects.
for example, if I want to create a variable that holds a k.boolean value to
use while scripting an application,
how do I create it, and then pass it to the set() method of a property
within that application?

let's say I'm scripting Adobe Illustrator:

```
il = app('Adobe Illustrator')
doc = il.current_document.get()
layers = doc.layers.get()
layer = layers[1]
```

in Illustrator, a layer object has a property layer.visible, which has a
k.boolean value.

how do I create a variable m which is a k.boolean type, such that:

```
layer.visible.set(m)
```

will set the .visible property to a different k.boolean value?

```
m = k.boolean(True) # doesn't work
m = make(new k.boolean) # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appscript will perform casts from Python types to the Apple Event types internally, so you can use a normal Python `bool` variable:

Make the layer visible:

```
flag = True
layer.visible.set(flag)
```

Toggle the layer on/off:

```
flag = not layer.visible.get()
layer.visible.set(flag)
```

The Python type -> AE type mapping [can be found here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/appscript-manual/06_classesandenums.html).

Comment: of course it's that simple! Thank you. I somehow missed that mapping in the docs.